# Invalid free() when trying to reorder a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, valgrind

I am attempting to reorder a linked list by swapping the pointers around. It works until I try to free the memory and then it gives me an error.

I have gotten it to work, by swapping the data and not the pointers, but I am curious as to why this causes an issue with my memory. Here is my code

```
typedef struct myArray {
    void *data;
    struct myArray *next;
} myArray_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    myArray *ma = paramsToList(argc, argv);
    revArray(&ma);
    printArray(ma);
    free(ma);
    return 0;
}

myArray_t *paramsToList(int ac, char *const *av) {
    myArray *ma = (myArray*)malloc((ac) * sizeof(myArray));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ac) {
        ma[i].data = av[i];
        if (i < ac - 1) {
            ma[i].next = &ma[i + 1];
        } else {
            ma[i].next = NULL;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return ma;
}

void revArray(myArray_t **begin) {
    myArray *cur = begin[0];
    myArray *prev = NULL;
    myArray *next = cur->next;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        cur->next = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur = next;
        if (cur != NULL) {
            next = cur->next;
        }
    }
    begin[0] = prev;
}
```

When I run the code I get this error

```
valgrind ./a.out one two three

three
two
one
./a.out
==3662== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3662==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3662==    by 0x400604: main (example.c:20)
==3662==  Address 0x51fc070 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 64 alloc'd
==3662==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind    /vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3662==    by 0x40062B: paramsToList(int, char* const*) (example.c:26)
==3662==    by 0x4005DC: main (example.c:17)
==3662== 
==3662== 
==3662== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3662==     in use at exit: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==3662==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 64 bytes allocated
==3662== 
==3662== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3662==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==3662==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3662==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3662==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3662==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3662== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3662== 
==3662== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3662== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: what is wrong with for() loops?  #style

Comment: `for( i = 0; i < ac; i++ ) { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: `for( ; cur != NULL; next = cur->next ) { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: PSA: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 4):

You can only pass to `free()` a pointer that was returned by `malloc()/realloc()/calloc()` and you are passing a node that is a pointer to a `ma` plus some offset, precisely `&ma[ac - 1]`.

You could just change the content of the nodes instead of the nodes themeselves, or just write a normal linked list where every node is just allocated with `malloc()`.

Comment: The problem is in `begin[0] = prev;`. Since `begin` is `&ma`, changing `begin[0]` changes `ma`. So when you `free(ma)`, you aren't freeing the same address you got from `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass the original pointer returned by `malloc()` to `free()`.

Since `revarray` modifies the pointer received by address, you must save the original pointer to later pass to `free()`.

Also note that `revArray` can be simplified by removing the test to set `next`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct myArray {
    void *data;
    struct myArray *next;
} myArray_t;

myArray_t *paramsToList(int ac, char *const *av) {
    myArray *ma = (myArray *)malloc(ac * sizeof(myArray));
    if (ma == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < ac; i++) {
        ma[i].data = av[i];
        if (i < ac - 1) {
            ma[i].next = &ma[i + 1];
        } else {
            ma[i].next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return ma;
}

void revArray(myArray_t **begin) {
    myArray *cur = *begin;
    myArray *prev = NULL;
    myArray *next = cur->next;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        next = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur = next;
    }
    *begin = prev;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    myArray *ma = paramsToList(argc, argv);
    myArray *orig_ma = ma;
    revArray(&ma);
    printArray(ma);
    free(orig_ma);
    return 0;
}
```